# How to correctly identify pure functions in functional programming?

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

Is this function pure or impure?

```
function greet(name) {
    return "Hi I'm " + name;
}
```

The property of pure function is that it has no side effects and always returns the same output for the same input.

Here, it produces side effects (returning a string).
The string concatenation, `"Hi, I'm " + name`, introduces a dependency on external state. Impurity is made from  "Hi, I'm " .

We can rewrite the code below to make it pure.

```
//pure function
function pureGreet(greeting, name) {
    return greeting + name;
}

//console output
const hiGreeting     = "Hi, I'm ";

const actualGreeting = pureGreet(hiGreeting, "John");

console.log(actualGreeting);
```

Is this explanation correct?

Comment: As long as the same inputs always produce the same output (and do not modify anything from the outside), the function is pure. Both of your functions are "pure".

Comment: What about the string "Hi, I'm "?

Comment: A return value is *not* a "side effect". Functions return values.

Comment: impure functions are those whose output depends on external state, like say math. Random or maybe user input. In pure functions like you said for the same input you get same out always, both the above functions follow this property

Comment: @DevindeSilva does the function do the same thing to the same input whenever you call it?

Comment: Does pure functions should contain some kind of computation inside the function? Can't we take "Hi I'm" as a side effect because we haven't given it  as an argument?

Comment: If the function doesn't modify the input in some way, what's the point? It's still a consistent return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that explanation isn't correct.

> Here, it produces side effects (returning a string)

No, returning a value is *not* a side effect. That's what functions do.

The string `"Hi I'm "` is a *constant*, so that doesn't change the characteristics of what constitutes [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency):

- Does it always return the same output given the same input? Yes.
- Does it have any side effects? No.

Therefore it's a pure function.

Constants are just constants. You could imagine another function that always adds 2 to its input:

```
function add2(i) {
    return 2 + i;
}
```

This is pure as well, since `2` is a constant. `add2(2)` always returns `4`, and `add2(3)` always returns `5`, and so on.

> The string concatenation, "Hi, I'm " + name, introduces a dependency on external state

The string `"Hi, I'm "` is actually not external to the function body, but an implementation detail.

That said, depending on external state is not in itself cause for impurity, as long as that external state is immutable. That's what *closures* do.

---

There is, by the way, a subtle distinction between *purity* and *referential transparency* that Tyson Williams has pointed out to me. It mostly becomes important in languages like Haskell, but the bottom line is that you can have referentially transparent functions with 'impure implementations'. The F# base library does this a lot.

If you're really interested, I don't know of a better place to link to than the long thread where Tyson Williams originally made me aware of that distinction: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/02/24/discerning-and-maintaining-purity/#d28c24c07228400f9ed141f97b5c72b5

Comment: Can we think 2+i as a computation, but adding string constant "Hi I'm" as not a computation and take greet function as impure?

Comment: @DevindeSilva I think you're doing the mixing of layers thing I mention in my answer still. Strings and integers and everything else *are just bytes*, there is no difference except what the semantics of a programming language imposes on top of them. It's still a computation in the relevant sense. There's nothing impure about your function *in the context of Javascript*.

Comment: why adding 2 in add2 function doesn't make it impure?

Comment: @DevindeSilva It neither makes the function nondeterministic nor does it induce any side effects. Why do you think it makes the function impure?

Comment: @DevindeSilva allow me to phrase Mark Seemann's question slightly differently: if `f(x) = x + 2` (regardless of syntax in a particular programming language) is not a pure function, then what is, and how does it form a meaningfully discreet category from the function I defined? And NB I wrote that in mathematical notation rather than in programming syntax to hopefully underscore the point.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that you aren't mixing up different layers of abstraction when pondering these sorts of things.

If you dig down far enough, there's no such thing as a pure function: side-effects are happening like memory allocations, swaps, moves, etc. Go down another level and transistor states are changing in silicon wafers, heat is being produced and redirected, etc.

But that's *usually* the wrong layer at which to consider "does this function have side-effects" even in a manually managed language like Rust or C: the question you *should* be asking is "does the caller always get back the same returned value for the same inputs?"

There are exceptions but they're rare: for instance if you are writing an OS kernel then it may matter very much whether a function could potentially allocate memory because that allocation might fail and you can't just crash or have random behavior. But *usually* we don't worry about that and can safely treat that sort of thing as an implementation detail that *normally* doesn't leak out.

So it depends: in what context are you asking the question? Because in the context of the Javascript example you posted that function is pure at any level you could possibly be concerned about when writing Javascript. But in another context/language you might be worried about the implicit side-effect of the allocation to hold the concatenated string.

Comment: Can you suggest a text book or any other reference related to this?

Comment: @DevindeSilva this is probably a good place to start https://mostly-adequate.gitbook.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch03. Since you seem to be highly demanding of rigor If you want something meatier there is always [TAPL](https://www.amazon.com/Types-Programming-Languages-MIT-Press/dp/0262162091).